# Handle large numerical value in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

I have few Number textbox (with data type Number) in which user can add large numerical values (approx of **12 to 15** digits like `12345678901234`).

Now when I am storing it into a number and passing it to Java (using BlazeDS) it is actually going in an exponential format like `1.79769313486231e+308`.

How can I handle this in such a way that flex will pass a proper numerical value to Java instead of exponential format?

Comment: What value type are you passing it as?  Number?  int?  uint

Comment: So you want to see 179769313486231 followed by many zeros as opposed to 1.79769313486231e+308?  Is 1.79769313486231e+308 the correct value as expressed in scientific notation, or are you expecting to see just 179769313486231?

Comment: I am expecting to see 179769313486231

Comment: Well that number is bigger than [Number.MAX_VALUE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#MAX_VALUE) so your only option is to use a `uint` instead; that is if your number is always positive and doesn't have a fraction. btw: I don't know what type you're using on the Java end, but this will exceed `float`'s maximum value as well, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ActionScript's uint only goes up to 4,294,967,295. Sounds like that's not high enough for you. There's no way for Java to tell that you meant the Number as a uint instead of a floating point. You could fix it on the Java side.

Maybe consider just treating these values as strings. I know it's a bummer, but String would seem to be ActionScript's best fit data type for your huge numbers.

Are they serial numbers or something?

Answer (score 0):

`1.7+e308` is no way a `15-digit` number. 
`15 digits` fit well into `2^64`, so `Number` type is ok for it.
It is naturally converted to Java's `double` type.

Exponential form is just a way to convert internal value to human-readable string, so you shall just use different formatting when converting `double` to string.